# Loading a CNN from checkpoints and feeding it in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming that I have a simple network including a CNN with a specific name. We can save the checkpoints using tf saver and restore it with tf.saver.restore (checkoiints address). We also can get all tensors and operations in the graph using tf.graph_def().get_operations() and etc. 
For my specific question, I load a CNN layer from checkpoints which look likes:

```
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal/shape',
'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal/mean',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal/stddev',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal/TruncatedNormal',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal/mul',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/truncated_normal',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/Const',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/Conv2D',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/add',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/Relu',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Switch',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/switch_t',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/switch_f',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/pred_id',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Const',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Const_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch_2',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch_3',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch_4',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Merge',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Merge_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond/Merge_2',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/Switch',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/switch_t',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/switch_f',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/pred_id',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/Const',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/Const_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/cond_1/Merge',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg/sub/x',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg/sub',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg/sub_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg/mul',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1/sub/x',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1/sub',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1/sub_1',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1/mul',
 'tower_0/conv1_fullres/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg_1',
```

Naming is in a common way. My Question is How can I feed an image to this convolution layer and get results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the model is saved with `write_meta_graph=True`, it will create meta file which we can load to create the network, else you have to write python code to create each and every layer manually as the original model.

You can use [`tf.train.import_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) function to load meta-graph. This will append the network defined in `.meta` file to the current graph, but will not load any parameters values.

We can restore the parameters of the network by calling restore on this saver which is an instance of `tf.train.Saver()` class.

Read more here:
- [Saved models - Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)
- [A quick complete tutorial to save and restore Tensorflow models](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/)
- [Code example on Colab on Save and restore model](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models.ipynb#scrollTo=pZJ3uY9O17VN)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to now how to feed a tensor to CNN after I get it by "tf.get_tensor_by_name()" ? in my question the CNN layer names is "conv1_fullres", but it has different parts